# Is there a conventional way for organizing a Rust project?

Tags: rust

Is there is a standard fashion for organizing a Rust project? I have been working with C-family programming languages for over nine years, but Rust seems different in some aspects.

Is one supposed to organize their projects in a similar manner to C-family languages, especially object-oriented such?

```
project
|->src
   |->main.rs
   |->structs.rs
```

Or perhaps in this way?

```
project
|->src
   |->main.rs
   |->struct0.rs
   |->struct1.rs
   |->struct2.rs
   |->struct3.rs
```

That is, one file per struct?

Or does one create new binary projects every time they make a new part of their program? I am currently using Cargo to generate my projects, but to be fair do not know too much about it. Eventually, there will come a point when I read through the entire Cargo documentation, although I would like to get a little more acquainted with Rust prior to that.

Kindly explain in both trees and text, as well as possibly some pieces of code.

Comment: This is dangerously close to "primarily opinion based". But I think it's valid to ask for some basic guidelines about project/module design. *belst* mentiones one guideline: organize by logic. And there is absolutely no "one module per struct" rule! Especially in Rust, it wouldn't make any sense to define only one type per module.

Comment: Oh and usually, you can learn from big, existing Rust crates, for example `std` itself!

Comment: "Primarily opinion based", I tried my best not to, did I not? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to plan how your program will be organized in terms of logic rather than objects. Split your logic into separate modules.

If a you have a small module make it a single file `modname.rs` or if it is a bigger module (consisting of submodules) create a folder with at least a `mod.rs` file in it: `modname/mod.rs`.

If your project gets really huge you could also split it into several crates (libraries) which you then depend on in your main project.

You can read more about Rusts crates and module system in the official rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html

Comment: Slightly confusing: whether to save the module "foo" in `foo.rs` or `foo/mod.rs` doesn't directly depend on the size of the module, but whether or not it has submodules/children. Usually, only modules saved in `foo/mod.rs` may have child modules. Maybe you want to clarify that in your question? :)